# Uncaught error in the transformer worker

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to run a sample code from react-player's repository.
But I continue to get the following error :

```
Error: Uncaught error in the transformer worker: /Users/idesirejustice/Projects/Tests/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native/packager/transformer.js
  at _transform.then.catch.error (/Users/idesirejustice/Projects/Tests/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/JSTransformer/index.js:110:33)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

I have tried:

- downgrading the babel.
- upgrading the react-native and react.
- reinstalling everything.
- throwing the computer out of the window.

Unfortunately, none of them helped.

Comment: What exactly is the code in question? Please post it

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react'

type Props = {
  children: Element<any>
}
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import 'whatwg-fetch'
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

class App extends Component {
  render (){
    return <ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' playing />
  }
}